# binance.exception.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permission for action

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip, binance-api-client, python-binance

I am trying to connect to my Binance account using Python and a Raspberry Pi. I keep having this issue

My code is realy simple

```
from binance import Client
apiKey = ''
apiSecret = ''

client = Client.(apiKey, apiSecret)
client.get_account()
```

The client.API_URL is 'https://api.binance.com/api' if usefull

When I try this without the IP whitelist on Binance it works, but when I activate the IP whitelist it shows me this error. I already checked multiple time if my IP was realy correct and I already changed IP, I also tried to create another API key and always the same problem ...

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. I was using my private IP (the one showing when you make ifconfig command) instead of public IP address